# Is it possible to have an animated QSystemTrayIcon?

Tags: c++, qt

I can't seem to find any info about this. but a lot of kde apps use animated icons.

As i know it setting as QIcon a gif won't work, as only first frame will be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't try this but it is probably possible by setting new icon every few milliseconds.

```
/* list of frames */
QLinkedList<QIcon> frames;
/* frames are icons created from images in application resources */
frames << QIcon(":/images/icon1.png") << QIcon(":/images/icon2.png");

/* set timer */
QTimer timer = new QTimer(this);
timer->setSingleShot(false);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateTrayIcon()));
timer->start(500); /* update icon every 500 milliseconds */
/*
updateTrayIcon function (SLOT) sets next tray icon
(i.e. iterates through QLinkedList frames)
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you have two ways:

1. Try to use GIF animated file (start playing with GIF with [QMovie](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qmovie.html)), and place it to the tray (i'm not sure about this case)
2. The other way is to use [QTimer](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qtimer.html) and a few different images. Here I found [an example](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d630243/c-cpp/bibliotheques/qt/systray-anime-qt/#post3715374).

Answer (score 1):

I did like this:

```
QMovie *movie = new QMovie(":/icons/icon.gif");
QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);
label->setMovie(movie);
movie->start();

QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
timer->setSingleShot(false);
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [this,timer,label](){
    trIcon->setIcon(label->movie()->currentPixmap());
    timer->start(50);
});
timer->start(50);
```